# How can "Modified By" be changed when using RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

Tags: security, sharepoint

We have a web part that uploads a document to a document library. The user uploading the document may not have access to the destination location, so the code adding the file executes within a [RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) block. This means the "Modified By" field is always set to System Account. Here is the code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
    delegate
    {
        using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        using (SPWeb targetWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(webUrl))
        {
            targetWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPFile newFile = files.Add(filename, file);
            SPListItem item = newFile.Item;

            // TODO: Insert code to set Modified By

            item.SystemUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

The "Modified By" field needs to be set to the name of the current user (at the TODO line above), but none of the following attempts have worked:

```
item["Modified By"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

item["Author"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

item["Modified By"] = new SPFieldUserValue(
SPContext.Current.Web, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID,
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name);

item["Author"] = new SPFieldUserValue(
SPContext.Current.Web, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID,
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name);
```

Does anyone know of a solution that allows the "Modified By" value to be changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some more testing...

```
item["Editor"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
item["Author"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
item.SystemUpdate();
```

Created By is set to the current user but Modified By is set to System Account.

```
item["Editor"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
item["Author"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
item.Update();
```

Both Created By and Modified By are set to the current user.

The problem was using [SPListItem.SystemUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx) which does the exact opposite of what the API documentation states, at least when running with elevated privileges.

**Note:** SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser does pick up the current user and not the system account when running within SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges. (Whether it should be used like this is another question.)

Comment: Weird behavior of the calls. Thanks for posting the solution. Helped me.

Comment: am having an issue in my document library where i have enabled check-in and check-out . so when my itemupdate is getting called i am still getting the modified by as "system account" and when I tried with listitem["Editor"] = ospuser.ID; , am again getting check out and check-in error. pls help

Answer (score 6):

One way to solve this is by storing the currently logged user in memory **before** elevating permissions. Later in the update request, replace the 'System account' with with your variable.

See below:

```
// Keep a reference of the Logged in user in memory
SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
delegate
{
    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
    using (SPWeb targetWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {
        targetWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPFile newFile = files.Add(filename, file);
        SPListItem item = newFile.Item;

        // Replace 'System Account' with current user
        item["Author"] = currentUser;
        item["Modified By"] = currentUser;

        item.SystemUpdate();
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do not forget to set targetWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates to false. You would like to do that in finally {} block.

Answer (score 1):

Do as (Henrique Zacchi) writes, but build a wrapper extension method that takes in SPUser as an additional param. Then use it.

Answer (score 1):

RunWithElevatedPrivileges always creates a new thread inside the current thread with the AppPool's identity. So, inside this delegate, context belongs to system account.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps impersonation might be an option helping you to solve your problem.

Some infos on that:
http://dotnet.org.za/zlatan/archive/2007/08/05/sharepoint-2007-impersonation.aspx
http://www.sharepointblogs.com/mirjam/archive/2006/11/02/impersonation-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead of SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext w = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero)) 
{
     //Do stuff here
}
```